Why only the concatenation is not running in this C chalenge?
I am trying to solve this HackerRank challenge:
There are 3 variables already declared: i(integer), d(double), and s(string).
I must declare 3 more variables of the same type as the previous, requesting input with scanf().
Then print sum of i with the second int variable. Then print the sum of d with the second double variable.
Finally, and the only task that I am not able to complete, is to concatenate the s string with the second char variable(string).
The first two tasks were completed smoothly, but the concatenation is not running.
I am getting  as output only the first string and 0. (HackerRank  0.)
Here is the code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "HackerRank ";
    
    int secondI;
    float secondD;
    char s2[100];

scanf("%d", &secondI);
scanf("%1f", &secondD);
scanf("%s", s2);

printf("%d\n",i + secondI);

printf("%.1f\n", d + secondD);

printf("%s ", s);
printf("%s", s2);



    return 0;
}

```
`

Expected Output
16
8.0
HackerRank is the best place to learn and practice coding!


My Output (stdout)
16
8.0
HackerRank  .0



scanf("%1f", &secondD); ==> scanf("%lf", &secondD);

The %s format for scanf read a space-delimited word.

You should always check scanf()'s return value to see if it succeeded or not.

And compile locally, instead of just in the HR web page, so you can enable compiler warnings, use a debugger, tools like valgrind, etc.

@pmg need to change the type of secondD too with that change.

@pmg good call, but the code has float secondD which I guess should be double secondD as the code already used double.

Right @Shawn, my bad. I just read the text which speaks of a double ... and I never use float when double works :-)

@Shawn, yes I realise that, thank you. It's what the 1 does.

"HackerRank is the best place to learn and practice coding!" Is a blatant lie.

@n.m.couldbeanAI one of the worse things is that the normally essential checks of scanf() can be skipped because a) the input is guaranteed to be as specified, b) it wastes coding effort and program execution time, and c) there is no recovery action, or sensible response, that can be done anyway. The program is incorrect, and will output the wrong answer. These sites should be treated as "coffee break" problems.

scanf("%1f", &fvar) reads one character and interprets that single char as a float value which is written into the variable. The rest of the input is then used for the next scanf().
Use scanf("%f", &fvar) with floats ... or scanf("%lf", &dvar) with doubles.
And also check the return value of scanf
if (scanf("%lf", &dvar) != 1) /* error in input */;

